# text file line reading issue

Tags: python, line

I have read the file content and trying to processing and print each line.

In this print, the content does not appear in new line rather in only one line. And line content remains overlapped, so only last line content appears.

```
    with  open('BSE_company_names_1.txt') as f:
            stuff = f.readline()
            print stuff #print content in one line in overlap fashion
            for data in stuff:
                print data # print each character
```

file content looks like

```
500002  BSE ABB ABB INDIA LIMITED   1
500003  BSE AEGISLOG    AEGIS LOGISTICS LTD.    2
500005  BSE AKARLAMIN   AKAR LAMINATORS LTD.    2
500008  BSE AMARAJABAT  AMARA RAJA BATTERIES LTD.   3
500009  BSE AMBALALSA   AMBALAL SARABHAI ENTERPRISES L  3
500010  BSE HDFC    HOUSING DEVELOPMENT FINANCE CO  3
500012  BSE ANDHRAPET   ANDHRA PETROCHEMICALS LTD.  2
500013  BSE ANSALAPI    ANSAL PROPERTIES & INFRASTRUCT  2
500014  BSE APPLEFIN    APPLE FINANCE LTD.  2
500016  BSE ARUNAHTEL   ARUNA HOTELS LTD.   2
500020  BSE BOMDYEING   BOMBAY DYEING & MFG.CO.LTD. 2
500023  BSE ASIANHOTNR  ASIAN HOTELS (NORTH) LIMITED    2
500024  BSE ASSAMCO ASSAM COMPANY (INDIA) LIMITED   2
500025  BSE ASSAMBR ASSAMBROOK LTD. 1
500027  BSE ATUL    ATUL LTD.   2
500028  BSE ATVPR   ATV PROJECTS INDIA LTD. 1
500029  BSE AUTOLITIND  AUTOLITE (INDIA) LTD.   1
500030  BSE AUTORIDFIN  AUTORIDERS FINANCE LTD. 2
500031  BSE BAJAJELEC   BAJAJ ELECTRICALS LTD.  2
500032  BSE BAJAJHIND   BAJAJ HINDUSTHAN SUGAR LIMITED  2
500033  BSE FORCEMOT    FORCE MOTORS LTD.   2
500034  BSE BAJFINANCE  BAJAJ FINANCE LIMITED   2
500036  BSE BALAJIIND   BALAJI INDUSTRIAL CORPORATION   2
500037  BSE BALMERL-B   BALMER LAWRIE FREIGHT CONTAINE  2
500038  BSE BALRAMCHIN  BALRAMPUR CHINI MILLS LTD.  2
```

What is the issue and how to resolve .

I want to read each line and split each value

Comment: It is unclear what you want. What is 'overlap fashion'? Also, you execute `f.readline()` exactly once, why do you expect to get more than one line from it?

Comment: What do you mean by `does not appear in new line rather in only one line`? As in it acts acts like a return carriage after every line? (if more lines are read)

Comment: Very unclear, but isn't the problem just that you use f.readline() instead of f.readlines() ?

Answer (score 1):

you need `readlines` not `readline`

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        for data in line.split():
            ....
```